# IE bug with Submit button

Tags: php, jquery, internet-explorer

I`ve created a team builder for my fantasy soccer site. It works fine on Chrome and Firefox, but not on IE. When I press one of the Submit-buttons on IE, the whole page reloads in that frame instead of the content in that frame.

Link for the test site: http://fantasysoccerpro.com/project/test-ny/

Screenshot of IE bug: http://fantasysoccerpro.com/iebug.jpg

```
//SELECT GOALKEEPER//

$database = "wp_fsprowpdatatable_3";
$goalkeeper="SELECT * FROM `fantasys_fspro`. `$database` where POSITION =     'G'";
$gk = mysqli_query(  $con, $goalkeeper );
?>

  <!-- Example row of columns -->

    <form method="post" action=" ">


        <select name="gk_">
        <option>----------Please Select G----------</option>
  <?php while($gkrow = mysqli_fetch_array($gk))
{ ?>
<option value="<?php echo $gkrow['wdt_ID'];?>"> <?php echo    $gkrow['player'];?></option>
<?php }?>              
        </select>
      </div>


      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="register" >Submit</button>


    </form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["register"]))
{

$gk_=$_POST["gk_"];

if ($gk_ > "0") {$selectedgk=$gk_;
}}

//UPDATE TABLE WITH GOALKEEPER//


$sql = "UPDATE $pw 
SET PLAYER= (SELECT PLAYER 
         FROM $database
         WHERE wdt_ID=$gk_) WHERE id = 1";

if ($gk_ > "0") {

if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {

} else {
echo "Error updating record: " . $con->error;
}}

$sql = "UPDATE $pw
SET SALARY= (SELECT SALARY 
         FROM $database
         WHERE wdt_ID=$gk_) WHERE id = 1";

if ($gk_ > "0") {

if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {

} else {
echo "Error updating record: " . $con->error;
}}

$sql = "UPDATE $pw 
SET PROJECTION= (SELECT PROJECTION
         FROM $database
         WHERE wdt_ID=$gk_) WHERE id = 1";

if ($gk_ > "0") {

if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {

} else {
echo "Error updating record: " . $con->error;
}}
```

Comment: is the code you posted  a frame? the question seems to be about a frame but your code has no frame so it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: additionally, if a form is submitting to the same page it is on, rather than having the action be empty, the proper convention is to omit the action attribute entirely

Comment: The site is build using the Divi theme for Wordpress. This is a module based theme where you can divide up the page in almost any way you like. I am actually unsure if they use frames to do this - I just used the term frame as that is what I suppose they are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your iframe, you have a form with an action attribute consisting of a single space. Internet Explorer interprets this as the form being supposed to post to the root of the page instead of the source of the iframe. Remove the action attribute entirely, as suggested by @chiliNUT, to solve your problem.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanx a lot!